# Site for computer repair questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was wondering which is the right site for asking computer repair questions, those related to physical hardware maintenance.

Two example questions:

> - What should I use for cleaning the old silicon thermal grease/paste from a processor?
> - What is the best for assembling some pieces of hardware?

I am hesitating between Server Fault and Super User. Is there a more specific site?

Comment: That example question - probably none. That's a very open question which would invite users to recommend their favorite products.

Comment: The example question is a technical question about which are the right materials which will properly cleanup the product without hurting the hardware ;)

Comment: Then make sure to phrase it as a real technical question. If you phrase it along similar lines as you've done now, you might get into trouble.

Comment: @Bart, thank you for your advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general topic of such a question would belong on Super User, not Server Fault.  Server Fault is for professional/enterprise level system administration, not personal computer related topics.

Additionally, the questions you've mentioned would still qualify for closure on SU as they are [shopping questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) for more information about recommendation/shopping questions and how you can improve them.

Comment: Not sure "how do I clean up thermal paste" is a shopping question, unless you're asking for prices / brandnames. FWIW: http://superuser.com/questions/267463/what-chemical-should-i-use-for-removing-thermal-paste

Comment: Oh, no, I'm talking about generic products. In fact, after more minutes of googling, I found [the exact question on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/132031/whats-the-proper-way-to-remove-thermal-paste-from-a-cpu/132032#132032)

Comment: @Shog9 The phrasing used above gave me the impression it was asking for specific products, unlike your rephrasing, which does not.  It's a small change, but still noticeable in my eyes.